# Pass `special_flags` argument to group.draw in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, drawing, pygame-surface, group

Is there a way to pass the `special_flags` argument to `Group.draw` so that it calls the `.blit` method with those flags?
I've tried just passing it as a keyword argument like this:

```py
group.draw(surface, special_flags=pygame.BLEND_SOURCE_ALPHA)
```

but it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MarciAdam\PycharmProjects\pygame_stuff_1\main.py", line 394, in <module>
    group.draw(surface, special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MAX)
TypeError: draw() got an unexpected keyword argument 'special_flags'
```

I know I could do something like this:

```py
for sprite in group.sprites():
    surface.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect, special_flags=pygame.BLEND_SOURCE_ALPHA)
```

but I would need to duplicate a lot of the pygame code for the more complicated group types eg. `LayeredUpdates`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

It works in pygame version `2.3.0` now, see [the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw).
For older pygame versions see [Rabbid76's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75499681/19115554).

Answer (score 0):

The requested feature is implemented with Pygame version 2.3.0. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw). With this version, the code works and you can set the blending mode directly

```py
group.draw(surface, special_flags=pygame.BLEND_SOURCE_ALPHA)
```

---

Before Pygame 2.3.0, this optional parameter did not exist. If you are using an older version of Pygame, you must implement a workaround.

Draw the sprite with a "for" loop. I suggest to write a function for this or implement your own `MyGroup` class derived from `pygame.sprite.Group`:

```py
class MyGroup(pygame.sprite.Group):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args) 
    def draw(self, surface, special_flags=0):
        for sprite in self:
            surface.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect, special_flags = special_flags)
```

```py
group = MyGroup()
```

```py
group.draw(surface, special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MAX)
```

If you want to do the same for [`pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates) or [`pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates), you have to implement all the drawing features of these objects yourself.

---

**A completely different solution is to use [`pygame.sprite.DirtySprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.DirtySprite). This class is derived from `pygame.sprite.Sprite` and has an additional `blendmode` attribute which is its the `special_flags` argument of `blit`.**

```py
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.DirtySprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.dirty = 2
        self.blendmode = pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MIN
        # [...]
```

Note, `DirtySprite` only works with [`pygame.sprite.LayeredDirty`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredDirty) and all sprites in the group must be of this type.

Comment: How would I do this with `pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates` or `pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates`? Because I don't really want to copy out the entire source code of those `draw` functions unless I really have to.

Comment: @MarcellPerger You have to implement the layered update features all by yourself. There is no other way. You want a completely new feature, so you have to implement it.  So the answer is: what you want to do is not possible unless you implement it yourself.

Comment: @MarcellPerger [`pygame.sprite.DirtySprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.DirtySprite) might be a solution for you. However, this is a completely different approach.